# closest, next, siblings won't work. Dynamic form building

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that from user input on a previous page and through a button, allows users to define the number of "Attributes" they would like to assign to a device.

The page asks the user to define a name and type for each of these attributes. If the user chooses "Select Option List" from the select list, a button appears through a jquery append "add" which is supposed to allow the user to add a text input to add an option. However, using closest, next and siblings the operation wont work. It works without using any of these however it assigns a text input to every instance of the "option" class on the page.

For some reason the code doesn't work properly in fiddle so I have just had to copy and paste the whole page code.

```
<!-- Declare num variable from form on previous page -->
<?php echo "<script> var num=\"".$_POST['number-of-attributes']."\";</script>"; <script type="text/javascript>
//variable to count the number of attributes
count=0;
//Convert Php post to an int
num=parseInt(num, 10);
//This method inserts the number of attributes present in the param
function addAttribute (input) {

    for(var i=0; i<input; i++) {

        var template="<div class=\"new-attribute\">"
                 + "<h3>New Attribute</h3>"
                 + "<label for=\"attributeName"+count+"\">Name:</label>"
                 + "<input class=\"attribute\" type=\"text\" name=\"attributeName"+count+"\">"
                 + "<label for=\"attributeType"+count+"\">Type:</label>"
                 + "<select class=\"tattribute\" name=\"attributeType"+count+"\">"
                 + "<option value=\"text\" selected>Text</option>"
                 + "<option value=\"checkbox\">Checkbox</option>"
                 + "<option value=\"select-list\">Select Option List</option>"
                 + "<option value=\"notes\">Notes</option>"
                 + "</select>"
                 + "<div class=\"option\"></div>"
                 + "<div class=\"remove\">Delete</div>"
                 + "</div>";
            $(template).appendTo('#attributes');
            count++;
            $("input[id=count-field]").val(count);

    }           

}
//JQuery does its stuff
    $(document).ready(function() {


        //Add the required number of attributes
        if(num!=null) {

            addAttribute(num);

        }

        //Add one attribute on click
        $("#new").on('click', function() {

            addAttribute(1);
            //Remove current of clicked 
            $(".remove").on('click', function() {

                $(this).closest('.new-attribute').remove();

            });

        });

//Remove current of added
        $(".remove").on('click', function() {

            $(this).closest('.new-attribute').remove();

        });

        //select temp
        var select="<div id=\"new-option\">"
                 + "<div class=\"btn\">add</div>";   
                 + "</div>";
        var add= "<label for=\"attributeOption"+count+"\">Name:</label>"
                 + "<input class=\"attribute\" type=\"text\" name=\"attributeOption"+count+"\">";        
        //get value of select
        $('.tattribute').change(function() {

           //Add extra fields for select
            if (this.value == "select-list") {

                $(this).next('.option').append(select);
                $(".btn").on('click', function() {

                    $(this).next('.option').append(add);

                });


            }   
            //Remove extra fields if not a select
            else {

                    $(this).next('.option').empty();

            }

        });

    });
```

```
#new {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.remove {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background: green;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
<form id="form" name="new-user" action="update.php" method="post">

    <label for="device-name">Name of Device Type:</label>
    <?php echo $_POST['device-name']; ?>


    <div id="new">New Attribute</div>

    <div id="attributes">

    </div>

    <input id="count-field" class="hidden-field" type="hidden" name="total" value="">
    <input class="hidden-field" type="hidden" name="device-name" value="<?php echo $_POST['device-name']; ?>">

    <input class="submit-button" type="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: The only piece of php thats relavant to js simply prints out any number. So num= any number

Comment: Wonderful. Now please post the rendered HTML as the PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: It makes no difference. But heres a link to the live code... Fill out the 2 fields on the first page and it will bring you to the page im having trouble with. http://www.thechapwiththeharp.com/pass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate problem, the one call that doesn't work is when you try to find the `next(.option)` from a `.btn` that's because `.btn` is not a sibling of `.option`.

Now, you also have some issue with event delegation, your jQuery code can be optimized like this:

```
//JQuery does its stuff
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Add the required number of attributes
    if (num != null) {
        addAttribute(num);
    }

    //Add one attribute on click
    $("#new").on('click', function () {
        addAttribute(1);
    });

    //Remove action
    $("#attributes").on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).closest('.new-attribute').remove();
    });

    //select temp
    var select = "<div id=\"new-option\">" + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn\">add</button>"; + "</div>";
    var add = "<label for=\"attributeOption" + count + "\">Name:</label>" + "<input class=\"attribute\" type=\"text\" name=\"attributeOption" + count + "\">";

    //Select change action
    $('#attributes').on('change', '.tattribute', function () {
        //Add extra fields for select
        if (this.value == "select-list") {
            $(this).next('.option').append(select);
        }
        //Remove extra fields if not a select
        else {
            $(this).next('.option').empty();
        }
    });
    //Add action
    $("#attributes").on('click', '.btn', function () {
        $(this).before(add); //adjust this since I don't know exactly where you want to insert the new inputs
    });
});
```

Check this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/Zyese/)**

Note that I used proper `<button>` tags instead of divs for new, add and delete buttons.